Mode_switch not working in Ubuntu 24
I recently updated to Ubuntu 24 and my shortcuts in Intellij using AltGr stopped working.
I'm trying to do the same as this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77723880/intellij-pycharm-does-not-recognize-altgr-shortcuts-anymore-in-linux
However, "Mode_switch" simply doesn't exist. If I do:
cat << EOF > ~.Xmodmap
clear mod3
clear mod5
add mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift Mode_switch
EOF
xmodmap ~.Xmodmap

The changes in mod3 takes effect. So does the one on ISO_Level3_Shift. However, Mode_switch does not show.
xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_L (0xcc),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  ISO_Level3_Shift (0x6c)

Has Mode_switch been deprecated? How can I reactivate it?

So the problem was that keycode 203 was assigned to ISO_Level5_Shift, not mode switch. I needed:
keycode 203 = Mode_switch

In my xmodmap configuration
